# How to set correct index for this MySql query?

Tags: mysql, optimization, select, join, indexing

I have this query showing up in MySql slow query log. (It is not slow, but it is not using indexes right). I need some help on how to set up the index right.

```
SELECT tbladded.amount*SUM(tbladdeditem.amount)
FROM tbladded
INNER JOIN tbladdeditem ON tbladded.addedid = tbladdeditem.addedid AND tbladdeditem.deleted='False' 
WHERE tbladded.userid=100
AND tbladded.date='2012-01-01'
AND tbladded.deleted='False'
GROUP BY tbladded.addedid


id  select_type  table         type  possible_keys        key          key_len  ref               rows  Extra
1   SIMPLE       tbladded      ref   PRIMARY,userid_date  userid_date  8        const,const       1     Using where
1   SIMPLE       tbladdeditem  ref   addedid              addedid      5        tbladded.addedid  1     Using where
```

This is how the tables look like:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbladded` (
    `addedid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `amount` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `userid` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
    `deleted` enum('False','True') CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT 'False',
    PRIMARY KEY (`addedid`),
    KEY `userid_date` (`userid`,`date`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tbladdeditem` (
    `addeditemid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `amount` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `addedid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `userid` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
    `deleted` enum('False','True') CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT 'False',
    PRIMARY KEY (`addeditemid`),
    KEY `addedid` (`addedid`),
    KEY `userid` (`userid`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: is your 'GROUP BY tbladded.addedid' neccessary?

Comment: @user1027167 Oh sorry, the GROUP BY is needed, I had missed a SUM() in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
ALTER TABLE `tbladded` ADD INDEX 
`tbladdedIndex` (`userid`, `date`, `deleted`);
```

Comment: Yes, I have thought about adding "deleted" to the index also, but I was unsure if it was important as using "userid" and "date" will only give like 5-10 results. Maybe adding "deleted" then is just unnecessary?